# win32 Handles and multithread

Tags: c++, winapi, events, handle

In our application, there is a heavy use of win32 HANDLEs, using CreateEvent, SetEvent/ResetEvent, so as to perform synchronization mechanisms.

A colleague of mine has asked me if accessing the HANDLEs for events was thread-safe.

I could not answer, since HANDLEs are not thread safe for any GDI object...

But since events are aimed towards multithread synchronization, I could not imagine they arent thread safe.

Could you confirm this ?

Comment: For what it's worth, GDI and USER32 handles are a completely different beast than the Kernel HANDLEs: they do have handle in the name and are opaque values, but they are completely different behind the scenes. Also, it's not so much that GDI handles aren't thread-safe, so much that some of them may have thread *affinity*, or require use from a certain thread. That's a different concept than thread *safety*, though.

Comment: An event handle that is not thread-safe would be pretty useless. How are you going to use the event to signal another thread if it isn't safe to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All handles you obtain from functions in Kernel32 are thread-safe, unless the MSDN Library article for the function explicitly mentions it is not.  There's an easy way to tell from your code, such a handle is closed with CloseHandle().

What you *do* with the handle may not necessarily be thread safe, Windows won't help when you call SetEvent() twice but WaitForSingleObject() only once.  Which might be a threading race in your program, depending on how you use the event.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type of handle.

A synchronization handle (like one created by CreateEvent) is by definition thread safe.
A file handle, when written to by multiple threads simultaneously, not so much.